# android getWsUrl()

Tags: android

The method getWsUrl() is undefined for the type Configuration 
for this line

> AndroidHttpTransport _ht = new
>   AndroidHttpTransport(Configuration.getWsUrl());

how can ı solve it?

Comment: What is it supposed to do? There is no `getWsUrl` method for `Configuration`. In fact, there are no "*url*" methods for `Configuration` at all.

Answer (score 0):

You probably imported the wrong `Configuration`. Right now, your import likely points to `android.content.res.Configuration`.

However, your code snippet suggests you're using (parts of) some Google Code project, [`androidzon`](http://code.google.com/p/androidzon/). It has a `webservice` package that includes a [`Configuration`](http://code.google.com/p/androidzon/source/browse/TS1_Android/src/it/marco/webservice/Configuration.java?r=37) class with the method you're looking for. It appears to mean something like 'get webservice url'. You will want to correct your import and/or add the missing classes/libraries to your Android project.

Do note that you appear to be using old code, as the [latest revision of that `Configuration` class](http://code.google.com/p/androidzon/source/browse/TS1_Android/src/it/marco/webservice/Configuration.java) does *not* include the `getWsUrl()` anymore. In stead, there is a `getServerAddress()` method.